# Check Google Cloud Storage bucket exists via gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gsutil

I am writing a function to copy data between buckets through `gsutil rsync` command.

Just want to make sure if source and destination cloud storage bucket exists before starting `rsync` operation through `gsutil`.

Is there an existing way to check `cloud storage` bucket exists via `gsutil` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no existing mechanism via `gsutil` to check if a bucket exists.

References :

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil

### We can validate it this way

```
  gsutil ls | grep "$BUCKET_NAME"
  test $? -ne 0 && echo “Bucket $BUCKET_NAME doesn't exist, Exiting!!" && exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not testing if bucket exists, but checks if you have access to it. Still might be good enough

```
gsutil ls -b "${BUCKET_NAME}"
```

If you use `gsutil ls | ...` you are listing all the buckets in default project, so the list might get pretty long, and if the default project is not the one that holds the bucket, you may get false negative.